# Is there literature on the study of "eigenmatrices"?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Starting with a disclaimer: I will not be able to describe this with the correct terminology because I am trying to find the literature which I am unsure of it's existence. I will try to explain what I mean as I go.

Let's say I have a rank 4 (rank in the sense of tensor, 4 indices) 'matrix' $M_{ij,kl}$ for which the vector analog is a matrix in the ordinary sense: $A_{ij}$ (I am writing in index notation). The multiplication between these two objects is as follows
$$(M*A)_{ij}=\sum_{kl}M_{ij,kl}A_{kl}$$

Have these objects been studied much? For instance, is there a notion of an eigenmatrix, which satisfies
$$\sum_{kl}M_{ij,kl}A_{kl}=\lambda A_{ij}?$$
And do these eigenmatrices have nice properties, like spanning whatever notion of space $M$ describes? Is there a notion of a determinant?

Sorry if this is explained poorly.

Comment: As far as we see here, a $(3 \times 3) \times (3\times 3)$ tensor of rank $4$ is the same thing as a $9 \times 9$ matrix.

Comment: This is the ordinary notion of eigenvector, but where the underlying vector space is a space of matrices. So your $M$ is a linear map $\mathbb R^{n\times n}\to \mathbb R^{n\times n}$. Unpacking this definition, you will find $M$ has four $\mathbb R^n$ indices.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Yes that is true, you can do the same thing for a matrix, making it into a vector. I need to somehow study these objects without resorting to that (I am not writing code, and so I won't be manipulating specific objects).

Comment: @AlexArvanitakis So all of the theorems regarding eigenvectors follow in this situation? If we assume this $M$ has maximal rank and the dimension of its eigenspace is equal to its rank, then can we say that all $A$'s can be written as a linear combination of the eigenvectors of $M$?

Comment: Does the rank of $M$ as a tensor of rank 4—i assume the two meanings of rank are the obvious, but different, ones—agree with its rank as a linear map $\mathbb R^{n\times n} \to \mathbb R^{n\times n}$?  (Maybe this is obvious; I never think about rank except for rank-2 tensors.)

Comment: @LSpice No, I only used that word because I am familiar with its usage in terms of tensors, which practically is a statement about how many indices there are. If we are talking about rank as 'the number of linearly independent columns of the matrix', that is completely different. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @LucashWindowWasher, right, but in [a previous comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338379/is-there-literature-on-the-study-of-eigenmatrices#comment846393_338379), you said "$M$ has maximal rank", which makes no sense if you just meant "number of indices"; so I assumed that that useage meant [tensor rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_(intrinsic_definition)#Tensor_rank) in the usual sense.  So what I am asking is whether the tensor rank as an element of $V^{\otimes2} \otimes (V^*)^{\otimes2}$ agrees with the tensor rank as an element of $W \otimes W^*$, where $W = V \otimes V^*$.

Comment: @LSpice Yes sorry, in that comment I was referring to 'the number of linearly independent columns of the matrix' rank. I should not have used the word rank in the OP, as this is causing understandable confusion.

Comment: The point is: in all your formulas, you sum on both $k,l$ and never on just one or the other.  So there is no mathematical reason for two indices.  And you always refer to both $j$ and $k$ together, never one or the other.  There are, indeed, tensor considerations that consider the indices independently.  But your notion of "eigenmatrices" is not one of them.